# Setting homepage from an extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't find code to set my web page as Google Chrome homepage after extension install.

```
{
  "name": "Test.com",
  "version": "2.1",
  "description": "Set Site on Homepage",
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },

}

"code??": "http://test.com",
```

How to do this?

Comment: Read this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest and this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override

Comment: @belykh You should really convert that to an answer if you're willing to provide a tiny sample. I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: You need to understand how Stack Overflow works. Please take the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

Use `chrome_settings_overrides` section https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override.
Try this:

```
{
    "name": "Test.com",
    "version": "2.1",
    "description": "Set Site on Homepage",
    "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
    "chrome_settings_overrides": {
        "homepage": "http://test.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note the extra requirements: it must be a published item in the Web Store with a verified website associated.

Comment: dosnt working.   "Please fix the following errors: The manifest has an invalid homepage url that is not owned by the developer: http://www.text.com."

Comment: @go01go01go On that documentation page, read about Verified site requirement.

Comment: you are talkig abut this : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en   this i have done verify a site by meta tag

Answer (score -1):

> Settings overrides are a way for extensions to override selected Chrome settings. The API is available only on **Windows**.

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override)